# usage of "just as"

Tags: word-usage

This sentence is from longman advanced learner dictionary.

> equally as good, bad, big etc
>
> E.g-Brad is just as good as the others.

I want to know whether I can change this sentence
as the following.

> Brad is good just as the others.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is understandable

> Brad is good just as the others *(are good)*

more usually it is expressed as

> Brad is good **just like** the others.

The pattern

> **just as** *something* **as**

is often used to show equivalence

> Walking the short distance is **just as good as** riding a bike.
>   John is **just as good as** David at playing ball.

Answer (score 0):

**Just as** means **similiar to** or **Just like**

more usually it is expressed as

I am good at making chocolate just like professionals