# The use of just as

Tags: collocations

[image]

Can i ask you why should we put as in blank 24?

Comment: Unplanned cities like Tokyo and LA have grown _just as_ dramatically (as New York and Paris have).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [usage of "just as"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/112877/usage-of-just-as)

Answer (score 1):

Because ***just as*** means ***equally***, ***similarly***, ***likewise***.

"Unplanned cities such as Tokyo and Los Angeles have grown dramatically."

Yes, but have they grown *more* or *less* dramatically than other cities or perhaps *equally* dramatically?

"Thay have grown *less* dramatically."
"Thay have grown *more* dramatically."
"Thay have grown ***equally*** dramatically." = "They have grown ***just as*** dramatically."